# PHP - Get all values with specific array key from multidimensional array with unknown depth

Tags: php, arrays, counting

I'm currently trying to get all values with a certain key from a multidimensional array with varying depth.

Sadly I'm not really good at dealing with recursion, so I don't really know how to solve this problem on my own. Here's a sample array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 243
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 244
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 245
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 246
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 249
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 250
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 253
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 256
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 257
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I basically just need a simple array with all the ID's from the multidimensional array. In this case the needed result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 243
    [1] => 244
    [2] => 245
    [3] => 246
    [4] => 249
    [5] => 250
    [6] => 253
    [7] => 256
    [8] => 257
)
```

I hope somebody can help here.

Comment: You do of course realise that the array you say you want is impossible?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. Fixed it, @RiggsFolly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember this forever, keys/indexes must be unique and will be unique always.
Further, you can use array_walk_recursive to fetch ids from recursive array.

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v,$k) use(&$result){
    if($k == 'id') $result[] = $v;
});
```

[array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) — Apply a user function recursively to every member of an array

Comment: Ah, thanks, it works!
I know that keys have to be unique. Already fixed that part in my question. Just didn't think about it, when I posted the question.